# How to combine the selection conditions Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, now there are `CASES` in `SELECT`:

```
CASE WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (1,3) THEN detailtousers.DetailToUsersName
      WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (2) THEN medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesName
END AS DetailToUsersName

CASE WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (1,3) THEN detailtousers.idDetailToUsers
      WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (2) THEN medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser
END AS idDetailToUsers
```

Is it possible to combine these cases how as like:

```
    CASE WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (1,3) THEN detailtousers.DetailToUsersName, 
detailtousers.idDetailToUsers
    WHEN user.UsersTypeAccount IN (2) THEN medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesName, 
medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser
```

Comment: You should be able to but you won't be able to use `AS` for two columns

Comment: Unless the query is very complicated, it may be better to use `UNION`for this. I.e. `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE user.UserTypeAccount IN (1,3) UNION SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE user.UserTypeAccount = 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  `case` returns a single value, not multiple values.  To repeat the logic, you need to repeat the `case` statement.

Note that this is common across all databases that I know of.  MySQL (as with the others) conforms to the standard in this respect.

I would note that if you used table aliases that are abbreviations for your table name, the query would be easier to write and to read:

```
(CASE WHEN u.UsersTypeAccount IN (1, 3) THEN du.DetailToUsersName
      WHEN u.UsersTypeAccount IN (2) THEN mf.MedicalFacilitiesName
 END) AS DetailToUsersName
```